# BigQuery Dataset How to Remove Roles From dataset.AccessEntry

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I know that using Google Client Library(dataset.AccessEntry), we can update our roles to the specific dataset for the requested user ([Reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/updating-datasets#python)). But wants to know how to remove that access when roles have been changed like (from Reader to Writer/Owner, etc.).

I Want to do this deletion automatically like role, dataset name and email comes from the UI as input, python code should update the roles to the specific requested dataset. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to delete the entry from `dataset.AccessEntry` by using `remove()` method, which removes the first matching element (passed as an argument) from a list in Python. You need to specify `PROJECT`, `DATASET_NAME` and `role`, `entity_type`, `entity_id` for corresponding entry you wish to remove.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud.bigquery.dataset import DatasetReference

PROJECT='<PROJECT_NAME>'

bq = bigquery.Client(project=PROJECT)
dsinfo = bq.get_dataset("<DATASET_NAME>")

#Specify the entry that will loose access to a dataset
entry = bigquery.AccessEntry(
    role="<ROLE>",
    entity_type="<ENTITY_TYPE>",
    entity_id="<EMAIL>",
)

if entry in dsinfo.access_entries:
    entries = list(dsinfo.access_entries)
    entries.remove(entry)
    dsinfo.access_entries = entries
    dsinfo = bq.update_dataset(dsinfo, ["access_entries"])
else:
    print("Entry wasn't found in dsinfo.access_entries")

print(dsinfo.access_entries)
```

You can find the official documentation for `google.cloud.bigquery.dataset.AccessEntry` [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.dataset.AccessEntry.html#google.cloud.bigquery.dataset.AccessEntry).

Comment: Yeah, remove() method worked for me!!!  I really didn't know that AccessEntry has list types. Thanks for your help.

Comment: for some reason this code doesn't work anymore, it used to work but now the if condition on access entry object is not matching up with the dsinfo.access_entries - did anyone validated this scenario recently?